# include early stopping in C

Tags: c

I want to stop the for loop for validation set when the current accuracy is less than previous accuracy calculated in the loop.

```
for (int j = 0; j < epochs; j++) {
    DPRINT("Epoch %d: 000%%", j + 1);
    DTIME_START_COUNTER;
    for (int i = 0; i < train_data->m; i++) {
        X->data[0] = train_data->data[i];
        y->data[0] = train_labels->data[i];
        
        backprop(network, X, y);
        
        if (i % (int)mini_batch_size == 0 || i == train_data->m - 1) {
            DPRINT("\b\b\b\b%03.0f%%", i * 100 / (double)(train_data->m - 1));
            apply_derivation(network, mini_batch_size, training_rate);
        }
    }
    DPRINT("  Eval accuracy: %.2f%%\n",
    network_accuracy(network, eval_data, eval_labels, NULL));
}
```

Comment: What's the question?  Are you looking for `break`?

Comment: There is a `break` keyword for that.

Comment: Yes break, but I want to store accuracy (from network_accuracy) in array  and compare the value of two consecutive iterations

Comment: @SajidUllah Two consecutive iterations of the inner loop or the outer loop? Is it only `network` being changed by each iteration, `eval_data` and `eval_labels` remain the same?

Comment: What array? How is it declared? How are you appending to it?

Comment: @Schwern, The outer loop. Yes network changes and only eval_data, eval_labels remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes break, but I want to store accuracy (from network_accuracy) in array and compare the value of two consecutive iterations

You need to do something twice, or just finer control, do an [extract method](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method) refactoring and put the code in a function. Then call that function.

```
// Put allocation of structs into their own function.
// All the necessary allocation goes in here.
Network *Network_new() {
    // If you simply did `Network network` it would be automatically
    // freed when the function exits. To return a complex value,
    // allocate it on the heap.
    return malloc(sizeof(Network);
}

// Pass in everything it needs. No globals.
// I'm just guessing at the types.
// A proliferation of arguments might suggest the need for a struct
// to gather them together.
Network *do_the_thing(
  Data *train_data,
  Data *train_labels,
  Data *x, Data *y,
  size_t mini_batch_size,
  int training_rate
) {
    // Allocate a new Network struct.
    Network *network = Network_new();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < train_data->m; i++) {
        x->data[0] = train_data->data[i];
        y->data[0] = train_labels->data[i];
        
        backprop(network, x, y);
        
        if (i % (int)mini_batch_size == 0 || i == train_data->m - 1) {
            DPRINT("\b\b\b\b%03.0f%%", i * 100 / (double)(train_data->m - 1));
            apply_derivation(network, mini_batch_size, training_rate);
        }
    }
    
    // Presumably backprop and apply_derivation have changed network.
    return network;
}

// Allocate space for two Network pointers.
Network *networks[2];

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  // Save the results to the array.
  networks[i] = do_the_thing(
    train_data,
    train_labels,
    x, y,
    mini_batch_size,
    training_rate
  );
}

// Compare networks[0] and networks[1] as you like.

// Then free them.
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  free(network[i]);
}
```

Alternatively, pass in a pre-allocated return value. This is more flexible, but requires a bit more work in the code calling the function.

```
Network *do_the_thing(
  Data *train_data,
  Data *train_labels,
  Data *x, Data *y,
  size_t mini_batch_size,
  int training_rate,
  Network *network
) {
  // same as before, but don't allocate the network
}

// Allocate space for two Networks.
// Again, there may be additional allocation and initialization required.
Network networks[2];

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  do_the_thing(
    train_data,
    train_labels,
    x, y,
    mini_batch_size,
    training_rate,
    &network[i]  // pass in the pre-allocated memory
  );
}

// No need to free, it will be done automatically.
```